# server.py wont start, problem with unicode character in path

Tags: python, server, mkdir, oserror

Okay so I'm trying to run a server using python. When I try to start the server though I get this:

```
D:\Users\DearJohn28\Downloads\prgm>python3 server.py
INFO:engineio.server:Server initialized for threading.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 63, in <module>
    app.initialize()
  File "D:\Users\DearJohn28\Downloads\prgm\app.py", line 21, in initialize
    settings = initSettings()
  File "D:\Users\DearJohn28\Downloads\prgm\prgm\app\settings.py", line 30, in initSettings
    makedirs(settings['downloadLocation'], exist_ok=True)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '\u202aD:'
```

I had it work once before so I don't know what happened. As far as I can tell, when it's making a directory there is a unicode character triggering an OSError.

I would say that I'm not too skilled in python, but I follow direction well.

Here's where makedirs() comes in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import os.path as path
from os import makedirs

import prgm.utils.localpaths as localpaths

settings = {}
defaultSettings = {}


def initSettings():
    global settings
    global defaultSettings
    currentFolder = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    configFolder = localpaths.getConfigFolder()
    makedirs(configFolder, exist_ok=True)
    with open(path.join(currentFolder, 'default.json'), 'r') as d:
        defaultSettings = json.load(d)
        defaultSettings['downloadLocation'] = path.join(localpaths.getHomeFolder(), 'mymedia')
    if not path.isfile(path.join(configFolder, 'config.json')):
        with open(path.join(configFolder, 'config.json'), 'w') as f:
            json.dump(defaultSettings, f, indent=2)
    with open(path.join(configFolder, 'config.json'), 'r') as configFile:
        settings = json.load(configFile)
    settingsCheck()
    if settings['downloadLocation'] == "":
        settings['downloadLocation'] = path.join(localpaths.getHomeFolder(), 'mymedia')
        saveSettings(settings)
    makedirs(settings['downloadLocation'], exist_ok=True)
    return settings


def getSettings():
    global settings
    return settings


def getDefaultSettings():
    global defaultSettings
    return defaultSettings


def saveSettings(newSettings):
    global settings
    settings = newSettings
    with open(path.join(localpaths.getConfigFolder(), 'config.json'), 'w') as configFile:
        json.dump(settings, configFile, indent=2)
    return True


def settingsCheck():
    global settings
    global defaultSettings
    changes = 0
    for x in defaultSettings:
        if not x in settings or type(settings[x]) != type(defaultSettings[x]):
            settings[x] = defaultSettings[x]
            changes += 1
    for x in defaultSettings['tags']:
        if not x in settings['tags'] or type(settings['tags'][x]) != type(defaultSettings['tags'][x]):
            settings['tags'][x] = defaultSettings['tags'][x]
            changes += 1
    if changes > 0:
        saveSettings(settings)
```

prgm.utils.localpaths

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os.path as path
import sys
from os import getenv

userdata = ""
homedata = path.expanduser("~")

if getenv("APPDATA"):
    userdata = getenv("APPDATA") + path.sep + "mymedia" + path.sep
elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    userdata = homedata + '/Library/Application Support/mymedia/'
elif getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME"):
    userdata = getenv("XDG_CONFIG_HOME") + '/mymedia/';
else:
    userdata = homedata + '/.config/mymedia/';


def getHomeFolder():
    return homedata


def getConfigFolder():
    return userdata
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Can you add the code part where you use os.makedirs()?

Comment: Added as requested

Comment: can you add the code of: prgm.utils.localpaths?

Comment: Added as requested

Comment: i've copied your code and it worked, apparently in your case the unicode character "\u202a" is added at the start of the path, i have no idea where this happens on your machine, probably during the loading/saving to the json file, try to put some prints (or use a debugger) to see how settings['downloadLocation'] changes during the execution

Answer (score 0):

This call `makedirs(settings['downloadLocation'], exist_ok=True)` seems to indicate that too much information is sent to makedirs.
You need to extract the 'downloadLocation' from settings in the call by running `settings['downloadLocation']` to extract the value from your dictionary.

Comment: So something like  

`loc = settings['downloadLocation']` <br/>   
   
`makedirs(loc, exist_ok=True)`?